# How to use react native community voice event "onSpeechVolumeChanged"?

Tags: react-native, speech-recognition

When I stop speaking, the voice recognition module should ideally cease listening to prevent unintended inputs.
However, it seems that even when I'm silent, if there is speech nearby (from someone else, for instance), the module continues to capture audio input, leading to unintended behavior.

I've explored utilizing the onSpeechVolumeChanged event to detect changes in volume levels and potentially trigger the end of listening when silence is detected. However, I've been unable to implement this effectively to achieve the desired functionality.

Expected Behavior:

The voice recognition should cease listening when I stop speaking, regardless of any surrounding speech.
If there is no speech detected for a certain duration (indicating silence), the listening mode should automatically deactivate to prevent unintended inputs.

this is my code

```
const DefHome = () => {

  // voice recognition states
  const [recognized, setRecognized] = useState(false);
  const [pitch, setPitch] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [end, setEnd] = useState('');
  const [started, setStarted] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [partialResults, setPartialResults] = useState([]);
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response) { //response from my socket server
      textToSpeech(response);
    }
  }, [response]);



  useEffect(() => {
    Voice.onSpeechStart = onSpeechStart;
    Voice.onSpeechRecognized = onSpeechRecognized;
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = onSpeechEnd;
    Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;
    Voice.onSpeechPartialResults = onSpeechPartialResults;
    Voice.onSpeechVolumeChanged = onSpeechVolumeChanged;
    return () => {
      Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      Tts.setDefaultLanguage('en-US');
      Tts.addEventListener('tts-start', event => console.log('start', event));
      Tts.addEventListener('tts-finish', () => {
        _startRecognizing(); //app start listening to user again
        setResponse('');
      });
      Tts.addEventListener('tts-cancel', event => console.log('cancel', event));
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }, []);



  const onSpeechStart = e => {
    console.log('onSpeechStart: ', e);
    setStarted('√');
  };

  const onSpeechRecognized = e => {
    console.log('onSpeechRecognized: ', e);
    setRecognized('√');
  };

  const onSpeechEnd = e => {
    console.log('onSpeechEnd: ', e);
 
    socket.on('response', r => {
      console.log('respons', r);
      setResponse(r);
    });
    console.log('stoped');
    setEnd('√');
  };


  const onSpeechResults = e => {
    console.log('onSpeechResults: ', e);
    setResults(e.value);
    setText(e.value[0]);

    sendMessage(e.value[0]); //send to server socket

  };

  const onSpeechPartialResults = e => {
    console.log('onSpeechPartialResults: ', e);
    console.log('partial', e);
    setPartialResults(e.value);
  };

  const onSpeechVolumeChanged = e => {
    // console.log('onSpeechVolumeChanged: ', e);
    setPitch(e.value);
    // I think here I need to end the discussion if the volume is less then a value 
  };

  const _startRecognizing = async () => {
    setRecognized('');
    setPitch('');
    setError('');
    setStarted('');
    setResults([]);
    setPartialResults([]);
    setEnd('');
    try {
      await Voice.start('en-US');
      console.log(results);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  const _stopRecognizing = async () => {
    try {
      await Voice.stop();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  const _cancelRecognizing = async () => {
    try {
      await Voice.cancel();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  const _destroyRecognizer = async () => {
    try {
      await Voice.destroy();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    setRecognized('');
    setPitch('');
    setError('');
    setStarted('');
    setResults([]);
    setPartialResults([]);
   
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Pressable onPress={_startRecognizing} style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <Text style={{marginHorizontal: 12, marginVertical: 4}}>
          press to talk
        </Text>
      </Pressable>

    </View>
  );
};

export default DefHome;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```